# Arrow anchor points not showing properly in swift

Tags: ios, swift

[image: This is how anchor points now showing]   This is the code which i am using to draw an arrow and add anchor points to it. But We can add arrow in different directions, because of that reason the anchor points got misplaced. Is there anyone knows how i can place these anchor points correctly at the starting point of the arrow and end point of the arrow.

```
//
//  AnnotationArrow.swift
//  
//
//  Created by Alvin Varghese on 10/Mar/15.
//  Copyright (c) 2015![enter image description here][2]. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

protocol _Annotation_ARROW_PROTOCOL
{
    func valuesFromArrowSubClass(instance : AnnotationArrow)
}

class AnnotationArrow: UIView
{
    //MARK: Global Variables

    var startingPoint : CGPoint = CGPoint()
    var endingPoint : CGPoint = CGPoint()
    var arrowLength : CGFloat = CGFloat()
    var arrowPath : UIBezierPath = UIBezierPath()
    var selectedInBox_Activated_Anchor_Points = false

    var delegate : _Annotation_ARROW_PROTOCOL!

    //MARK: For resizing

    var kUserResizableViewDefaultMinWidth = 40.0
    var kUserResizableViewDefaultMinHeight  = 40.0
    var kUserResizableViewInteractiveBorderSize = 10.0

    //MARK: initFrame

    override init(frame: CGRect)
    {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    //MARK: initCoder

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
    {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    func passingValues(startingPointValue : CGPoint, endingPointValue : CGPoint)
    {
        self.startingPoint = startingPointValue
        self.endingPoint = endingPointValue

        var xDistance : CGFloat = self.endingPoint.x - self.startingPoint.x
        var yDistance : CGFloat = self.endingPoint.y - self.startingPoint.y

        self.arrowLength = sqrt((xDistance * xDistance) + (yDistance * yDistance))
    }

    //MARK: drawRect

    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect)
    {
        var tailWidth : CGFloat = max(4.0, self.arrowLength * 0.07)
        var headLength : CGFloat = max(self.arrowLength / 3.0, 10.0)
        var headWidth : CGFloat = headLength * 0.9
        var strokeWidth : CGFloat = max(1.0, tailWidth * 0.25)

        self.layer.shadowRadius = max(4.0, tailWidth)

        self.arrowPath = self.bezierPathWithArrowFromPoint(self.startingPoint, endPoint: self.endingPoint, tailWidth: tailWidth, headWidth: headWidth, headLength: headLength)

        self.arrowPath.fill()
        self.arrowPath.stroke()
        self.arrowPath.lineWidth = strokeWidth
        self.layer.shadowPath  = self.arrowPath.CGPath

        if self.selectedInBox_Activated_Anchor_Points
        {
            // Starting the code for - ResizableView anchor points

            var color : UIColor = UIColor.greenColor()

            var context : CGContextRef = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
            CGContextSaveGState(context)

            // 1 -  Drawing the bounding box

            CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, color.CGColor)
            CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, color.CGColor)
            CGContextMoveToPoint(context, self.startingPoint.x, self.startingPoint.y)
            CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, self.endingPoint.x, self.endingPoint.y )
            CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2.0)
            CGContextStrokePath(context)
            CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, color.CGColor)

            // 2 -  Calculate the bounding boxes for each of the anchor points.

            var startingSectionRect : CGRect  = CGRectMake(self.startingPoint.x, self.startingPoint.y, 20.0, 20.0)

            var endingSectionRect : CGRect = CGRectMake(self.endingPoint.x, self.endingPoint.y, 20.0, 20.0)

            // 3 -  Create the gradient to paint the anchor points.

            var colors : [CGFloat] = [1.0, 1.0]
            var baseSpace : CGColorSpaceRef = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
            var gradient : CGGradientRef = CGGradientCreateWithColorComponents(baseSpace, colors, nil, 2)

            // 4 - Set up the stroke for drawing the border of each of the anchor points.

            CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2.0)
            CGContextSetShadow(context, CGSizeMake(0.5, 0.5), 1)
            CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, color.CGColor)

            // 5 - Fill each anchor point using the gradient, then stroke the border.

            var allPoints : [CGRect] = [ startingSectionRect, endingSectionRect]

            for index in 0..<2
            {
                var currentPoint : CGRect = allPoints[index]
                CGContextSaveGState(context)
                CGContextAddEllipseInRect(context, currentPoint)
                CGContextClip(context)

                var startPoint : CGPoint = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(currentPoint), CGRectGetMinY(currentPoint))

                var endPoint : CGPoint = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(currentPoint), CGRectGetMaxY(currentPoint))


                CGContextDrawLinearGradient(context, gradient, startPoint, endPoint, 0)
                CGContextRestoreGState(context)
                UIColor.greenColor().setFill()

                //  CGContextStrokeEllipseInRect(context, CGRectInset(currentPoint, 1, 1))
                CGContextFillEllipseInRect(context, currentPoint)
            }
            // Restoring state to most recently saved state
            CGContextRestoreGState(context)
        }
    }


    //MARK: hitTest

    override func hitTest(point: CGPoint, withEvent event: UIEvent?) -> UIView?
    {
        if self.arrowPath.containsPoint(point)
        {
            self.selectedInBox_Activated_Anchor_Points  = true
            self.setNeedsDisplay()
            self.delegate.valuesFromArrowSubClass(self)
            return self
        }

        var boundingBox : CGRect = self.arrowPath.bounds

        if ((boundingBox.size.width < 80 || boundingBox.size.height < 80) && CGRectContainsPoint(boundingBox, point))
        {
            self.selectedInBox_Activated_Anchor_Points = true
            self.setNeedsDisplay()
            self.delegate.valuesFromArrowSubClass(self)
            return self
        }

        self.selectedInBox_Activated_Anchor_Points  = false
        self.setNeedsDisplay()
        return nil
    }


    //MARK: Creating Path

    func bezierPathWithArrowFromPoint(startingPoint : CGPoint, endPoint : CGPoint, tailWidth : CGFloat, headWidth : CGFloat, headLength : CGFloat) -> UIBezierPath
    {

        var length = hypotf( Float(endPoint.x) - Float(startingPoint.x) , Float(endPoint.y) - Float(startingPoint.y))

        var tailLength : CGFloat = CGFloat(length) - headLength

        var points = [CGPointMake(0, tailWidth / 2), CGPointMake(tailLength, tailWidth / 2), CGPointMake(tailLength, headWidth / 2), CGPointMake(CGFloat(length), 0), CGPointMake(tailLength, (-headWidth) / 2), CGPointMake(tailLength, (-tailWidth) / 2 ), CGPointMake(0, (-tailWidth) / 2)]

        var cosine : CGFloat = (endPoint.x - startingPoint.x) / CGFloat(length)
        var sine : CGFloat = (endPoint.y - startingPoint.y) / CGFloat(length)
        var transform : CGAffineTransform = CGAffineTransform(a: cosine, b: sine, c: -sine, d: cosine, tx: startingPoint.x, ty: startingPoint.y)

        var cgPath : CGMutablePathRef = CGPathCreateMutable()
        CGPathAddLines(cgPath, &transform, points, (UInt)(points.count))
        CGPathCloseSubpath(cgPath)

        var bezierPath : UIBezierPath = UIBezierPath(CGPath: cgPath)
        bezierPath.lineCapStyle = kCGLineCapRound
        bezierPath.lineJoinStyle = kCGLineJoinRound

        return bezierPath
    }

    //MARK: UITouch Methods

    override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent)
    {
        var touch : UITouch = touches.anyObject() as UITouch


    }

    override func touchesMoved(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent)
    {
        var touch : UITouch = touches.allObjects.last as UITouch
        var point = touch.locationInView(self.superview)

    }

    override func touchesEnded(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent)
    {
    }

    override func touchesCancelled(touches: NSSet!, withEvent event: UIEvent!)
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are considering your points to be rectangles when drawing them:

```
var startingSectionRect : CGRect  = CGRectMake(self.startingPoint.x, self.startingPoint.y, 20.0, 20.0)
```

You are then filling this rectangle with an ellipse (circle). That's obviously wrong because the point you are interested in is staying in the upper left corner while you want it in the center:

```
let pointSize = 20.0
var startingSectionRect = CGRectMake(self.startingPoint.x - pointSize / 2.0, self.startingPoint.y - pointSize / 2.0, pointSize, pointSize)
```